# Slicing into a Numpy Array with a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm sorting through five CSV files and slicing certain columns in each.

I want them to go into a single NumPy array, so I've written a function that will take in the index I've specified, and then loops over the five files and indexes each one to a list. After it's done it then puts it into the array

This just seems inefficient, I'm thinking there should be a way to go straight from the slice and pushing it to the array, forgoing the list completely.

Many thanks in advance

```
def create_array(all_files, column, row):
    
    complete_list = []
    for i in all_files :
       property_name = i.iloc[row:, column]
       complete_list.append(property_name)  
    complete_array = np.array(complete_list)
    
    return complete_array
```

Comment: appending to a list is a good choice when collecting arrays in a loop.

Comment: @hpaulj ok thanks, so is this pretty much the best way to do this? I'm probably being pedantic, but I'm trying to step out of beginner/intermediate level and really optimize my code where ever I can (ie, being Pythonic).

Comment: What is the precise type of `all_files` (and so `i`)? Is it a list of dataframe? If so, what is the type of the items in the target columns? Ideally, could you provide a reproducible example (eg. realistic random inputs)?